# PHP/Symfony3/Doctrine association returns NULL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 tables, one a GrowerProjection and one a Crop. One crop can have many grower projections associated with it. I came into this project with the underlying database already built, and in the database, Crop has a unique ID of, for instance, CROP-001, stored in a column called crop_ID. In the GrowerProjection table there is also a crop_ID field, which lets you see what crop a particular projection is talking about.

So now I have used Doctrine to generate entities, and I am now trying to tie these entities together. When I try to make a ManyToOne association, I always get a null value back. My questions are: 1. What am I doing wrong and 2. How do I debug these kinds of issues in the future?

I have tried validating the schema and updating the schema via the console, but that seemed to have no effect.

Here is a relevant snip from Growerprojection's entity:

```
/**
 * Growerprojection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="growerProjection")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Growerprojection
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crop")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cropId", referencedColumnName="cropId")
     */
    private $crop;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="grower_ID", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $growerId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="crop_ID", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $cropId;

    public function getReadyToLoadDt() {
        return $this->prjreadytoloaddt;
    }

    public function setReadyToLoadDt($theDate) {
        $this->prjreadytoloaddt=$theDate;
    }

    public function getCrop() {
        return $this->crop;
    }

}
```

I have tried that with the join column as crop_ID and cropId, as doctrine uses cropId but the actual tables use crop_ID. I have tried with and without the @ID directive. No change. crop is always null.

Here is the Crop entity part:

```
/**
 * Crop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="crop")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Crop
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commodity_ID", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $commodityId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="crop_ID", type="string", length=16)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $cropId;

    public function getCommodityID() {
        return $this->commodityId;
    }
}
```

Then, here is the controller's action:

```
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Growerprojection');
        $projections = $repository->findBy(
            array('growerId' => 'GROW-001'),
            array('prjreadytoloaddt' => 'ASC')
            );
        $myCrop = $projections[0]->getCrop();
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($myCrop);
        return $this->render('grower/growerTest.html.twig', 
            array('projections' => $projections));
    }
```

This finds a grower projection, that grower projection has CROP-001 as the cropId, and there is a crop in the crop table with the crop_ID of CROP-001.

The line \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($myCrop); will always produce NULL, and when I do a dump() inside the twig, I also see that the projection arrives and is populated, but the column crop is null.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I get this association to work, and how do I debug this in the future so I don't have to pester y'all about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happened:

The data tables did not have foreign key constraints built in. I couldn't get them to work, so I started a different project, copied over a couple of Doctrine files, and used the suggested form from Scorpion's suggestion. I then had Doctrine create the schema, and then the associations worked. The plan from here is to back up data currently in the database, edit all of the doctrine files to set up the associations, and then have doctrine re-create the database with the foreign keys in place correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For the mapping of the classes, the values of the `name` and `referencedColumnName` fields of the `@ORM\JoinColumn` have to be the actual column names of the sql table, not the fieldnames. See [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) for reference.

Your code should look like this

```
/**
 * Growerprojection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="growerProjection")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Growerprojection
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crop")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="crop_ID", referencedColumnName="crop_ID")
     */
    private $crop;

    ...

}
```

Yet I've not found a simple way to debug these kinds of errors. Best for me is, to be super careful while building up the associations.

Comment: Hello! I just tried that and I see no change in the outcome. I notice in the Symfony debug bar, it only did 1 database query.

Comment: Okay that doesn't sound too good. I have 3 ideas left: 1. have you tried to also remove the <code>@ORM\Id</code>? That could be in conflict with the mapping. 2. Have you cleaned up the cache with <code>bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup</code> after changing the mapping? 3. Is there a foreign key mapping also in the database, like it is the result of the mapping in the docs?

Comment: I believe the issue here might be a lack of foreign key mapping in the database. However, when I created them in the database and then exported the structure, I see no reference to the foreign key constraints. When I tell doctrine to schema:create --dumpsql, the SQL it dumps says nothing about foreign key constraints either. I think I see the problem, but still confused about the fix!

Comment: This is what Doctrine generates: CREATE TABLE growerProjection (grower_ID VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, crop_ID VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, warehouse_ID VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, prjReadyToLoadDT DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, prjDateOfDelivery DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, qtyInCases INT DEFAULT NULL, soldQty INT DEFAULT NULL, fulfilledDate DATE DEFAULT NULL, fulfilledQty INT NOT NULL, rejectQty INT NOT NULL, grade VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, shipQty INT NOT NULL, growerProjection_ID VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(growerProjection_ID)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: It doesn't reference crop_id as an index, or as a foreign key, which is weird, and growerProjection_ID is not set as an index either.